# scaleType is not editing my imageView's position

Tags: java, android

I made a little video which should show issue I have. It'll be much clear then if I tried to write it out.

I drag the image then I try to change it using scaleType as shown in a tutorial video I'm watching (most likely an older version of android studios). When he does it, it changes the position of the image of the screen. However, when I do it nothing happens.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48oBhEMKanM

I added a description and it the problem still persisted. When I edit using scaleType I get this error in my XML:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UbYn.png

When I press alt + enter to auto fix it. It adds that line into my code. If I change the scaleType again, I get the same error.

This is basically what I'm trying to acheive:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UATh8W1kyOg&feature=youtu.be

And this is my XML code thus far:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="416dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="sdfsfs"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_title"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

Comment: Can you paste your entire XML here and also what you are trying to achieve. You might be able to achieve your desired results programmatically.

Comment: Edited. Please take and look and thank you for helping.

Comment: I honestly can't think of the reason as I've spent the last 20 minutes messing about with the options and it's working fine on my side. However, you can try to change the API Version in Editor to 26 or 25 as you are currently using 27 (it's the android icon between Nexus 4 and AppTheme dropdown menu). Let me know if that does the trick or not.

Comment: Can you let me know where I'd go to change the API version?

Comment: Literally above the design view with the green android icon

Comment: Yeah, changed it and still same problem